# How does discourse/stackexchange do dynamic notifications

Tags: web, push-notification, notifications, webapi

When someone replies, you get sent a [dynamic notification](https://www.discourse.org/features):

[image]

However, I have never had to allow notifications:

[image]

So I figured they (discuss/stackexchange) can't be using the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API) or the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API). But I assume they aren't doing something as primitive as polling.

So how do modern sites do this without having you opt in to a chrome popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [Sever-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or [Web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373655/how-to-send-message-from-server-to-client-in-web-application